# Down Arrows doesn't fire KeyPress Event

Tags: .net, winforms

Does anyone know why the KeyPress Event doesn't get fired when the user presses a down arrow? I have to look for it in the KeyDown event. Is this just something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Um What is this in regards to? Which language are you talking about? Which API are you using? You're being pretty vague here so I don't think this question is going to be answered unless you're a bit more specific.

Comment: read the docs please? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the documentation of the KeyPress event (assuming you are using WinForms):

> The KeyPress event is not raised by
>   noncharacter keys; however, the
>   noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown
>   and KeyUp events.

The down arrow key isn't a character key, so this event shouldn't be raised for it.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using the KeyUp event for this. Because it triggers at the same time as the KeyPress event: when the button is released. I think this is the experience users are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyDown instead

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyData.ToString + " KeyDown")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyChar.ToString + " KeyPress")
    End Sub
End Class
```