# C# keypress doesn't capture 'delete' key

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added a keyPress event on a `ListView`. With a breakpoint on my event, I can see that most of the keys trigger the event. However, a few among which, the one I'm interested in (delete), just won't trigger my event.

Is that weird ? And no, there's no broken keys on my keyboard :D

```
    private void listView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete)
        {
            ListView target = (ListView)sender;
            if (target.SelectedIndices != null && target.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                string ric = target.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
                //target.Items.RemoveAt(target.SelectedIndices[0]);
                ListModels.getInstance().getModel("Vols").removeRic(ric);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include the code you're using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Down Arrows doesn't fire KeyPress Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496974/down-arrows-doesnt-fire-keypress-event)

Comment: It's not exactly the same but the answer at my dupe suggestion answers this.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The reason for this is that the KeyPress event sends a character to the control based upon the character-key you press. However, as you'd expect, the delete key does not represent a character and is thus a non-character key.

Therefore using the KeyPress event will do nothing as you have noticed. You should use the KeyDown or KeyUp Events, either of which will work absolutely fine. The nuance being whether you want your event to fire upon pressing, or letting go of a key.

Comment: you write " as you'd expect, the delete key does not represent a character." <-- perhaps you can elaborate on the delete key not being a character, given that if you look at an ascii table, char 8 is the backdelete character, and char 127 is the DEL (no doubt  forward delete) character. And also if one is talking about scancodes, https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html   I see a keypad delete listed.

Comment: Absolutely! To be more clear, the delete key is a non-character key, thus the KeyPress event doesn't fire because it sends a character to the control when you press a character key such as 'A' etc. If the delete key was a character key, the KeyPress event would trigger absolutely fine. I'll also add this to my answer for further reading.

Comment: ok but then can you explain that in light of the fact that backdelete and forward delete in the ascii table(which is a table of characters, a character set)? (and you're saying they're not characters)

Comment: Whilst you're correct in that DEL has a reference in the ASCII table, it's a control character. It does not represent a printable ASCII character (which is the point which should be self-explanatory) and is thus, a non-character key.

Comment: a control character is a character. and del is a key. So why are you saying it's a non character key. Sure it's not a printable character key, but it is a character key. It is a control character key. A control character key is a character key

Comment: You're looking into this way too much, refer to the MSDN documentation for the KeyPress event. In this context, ASCII control characters are referred to as non-character keys.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

'The KeyPress event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace; however, the non-character keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.'

You've also got to bare in mind that we're talking about characters and controls, calling them control character keys would just be way too confusing.

Comment: You should really clarify your answer and state that it's according to the terminology of the the .NET framework or MSDN documentation,  to be a character it'd have to be printable, and thus delete, in that MSDN/.NET terminology, is not a character.  (contrary to the classical terminology where Delete is Certainly a character).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116470/discussion-between-barlop-and-bradley).

Comment: You're just repeating yourself in different ways and I'm not sure what your intention is here. There is no need for clarification unless specifically requested for; if you had to explicitly describe why you're using conventions every time you use them, they would be completely impractical. The convention within this environment is to call ASCII control characters non-character keys, the onus is on the person who does not know the conventions of a specific language or environment to understand why things are referred to in a particular way by either asking or doing the necessary research.

Comment: There seem to be edge cases, take Unicode Delete `'\u007f'` which happily shows up in `KeyPress` if you press `Ctrl + Backspace`

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use the `KeyDown` event for this.

Answer (score 5):

In KeyDown use the condition as follows,

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
{
   // Your Logic....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `keyDown` instead; `keyPress` is something like a full `keyDown` + `keyUp`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you set EditMode property to EditOnEnter it won't fire. If you use EditOnKeyStrokeOfF2 it will fire the event

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution where the user should only be able to choose from the defined items, then I believe you can do it with this:

```
  private void DropDownRank_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(ListView_KeyUp);
}

/// <summary>鍵盤觸發 ListView 清單</summary>
private void ListView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ListView ListViewControl = sender as ListView;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in ListViewControl.SelectedItems)
        {
            ListViewControl.Items.Remove(eachItem);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the stuff mentioned above but nothing worked for me, so im posting what i actually did and worked, in the hopes of helping others with the same problem as me:

Add an event handler in the constructor:

```
public partial class Test
    {
    public Test()
        {
            this.RemoveHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(Test_KeyDown)); 
            // im not sure if the above line is needed (or if the GC takes care of it
            // anyway) , im adding it just to be safe  
            this.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(Test_KeyDown), true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     //....
      private void Test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                //your logic
            }
        }
    }
```