# The textbox should never be empty. c#

Tags: c#, wpf, null, textbox

I don't want my Textbox to be empty. I want it to keep the value before it is empty and write it when it is deleted. I'm using the KeyDown event but it doesn't work. Not triggering when the Delete key is pressed. Which event would be appropriate to trigger this correctly.

My Code

```
private static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);
        var oldValue = textBox.Text;
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if (textBox.Text == string.Empty || textBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not null");
                textBox.Text = oldValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try `e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188328/c-sharp-keypress-doesnt-capture-delete-key). Please also double check, if this method is actually a `KeyDown` and not attached to `KeyPress`. This gets set in your textBox options.

Comment: What about when pressing Backspace ? Isn't it better to use TextChanged event and have the text saved in a variable ?

Comment: How can I keep the previous data if I use TextChanged. As soon as I press the delete button, I can retrieve the data written in the Textbox.

Comment: I use wpf. Keypress event not found in Wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle `TextChanged` and store the previous value in a field:

```
private string oldValue = string.Empty;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not null");
        textBox.Text = oldValue;
    }
    else
    {
        oldValue = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Note that `oldValue` will be reset on each keypress. Also note that `string.Empty` is equal to `""` so you don't need two conditions to check whether the `string` is empty.